# razor string manipulation

Tags: asp.net, razor

I have a razor string

```
 @postername.Substring(0, @postername.IndexOf("@"))
```

If the username has email I get the username before @ sign but if the username doesn't have email I want to have that whole word, how to do ?

```
 if(@postername.Contains("@")){
             @postername.Substring(0, @postername.IndexOf("@"))
            }else{
            @postername
            }
```

but didn't work, pls help

Comment: Can we see the code in your View around that line of code?

Comment: Define "didn't work."  Was there an error?  What was the input and what was the output?  Also, do you really need all of those `@`s in the code?  Maybe I'm mistaken, but I think you begin the code with an `@` (like, before your `if`) and then that makes it a code block.  You don't use it for all of the variables.

Comment: To be honest this really isn't logic you should be shoving into your view. I would do this in your ViewModel, or controller before sending it down.

Comment: The error was Server Error in '/' Application.
Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you must do this at View level, build the logic into a variable first:

```
@{

 string posternameShort = postername;

 if(postername.Contains("@")){
     posternameShort = postername.Substring(0, postername.IndexOf("@"))
 }

}
```

Then call the new variable:

```
@posternameShort
```

Answer (score 0):

To further clarify this, Razor functions (what appears in the code block between `{` and `}`) [fully support C# code](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-%28c%29). Additionally, [Visual Basic code is supported](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-%28vb%29) as well.

This is powerful. Any string manipulation that would occur in C# or Visual Basic, is also available to use in Razor code.

More info on this available [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timlee/archive/2010/07/30/using-functions-in-an-asp-net-page-with-razor-syntax.aspx) and [here](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Razor-Functions-and-Helpers.aspx#s3-functions-in-c).

[Curt's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13916281/2658159) outlines a basic way to do this, but I thought it would be good to explain the "why" behind the "how," especially since I've been looking into how to manipulate strings with Razor myself.